# why am I getting the below error while running the Chrome driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
package AutomationSample;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32");
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(); 
    
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
```

the above is my code and I have added all the selenium related jars into the project.

am getting the  below error while running the Chrome driver:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class AutomationSample.HelloWorld

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

I am using Chrome - Version 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

and I am using chrome driver - 32 bit and my OS is windows 10 -64 bit.

Can you please help me to rectify this error?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32");
```

has to be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
```

you forgot `.exe`

Answer (score 0):

cause you are missing class and method, one such method is `main()`

You need to have a method like below :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {  
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(); 
    
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");

}
```

and obviously a class in which you will have this method.

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey , Thanks for your reply. I am getting the same error even after including the class and main() method.

Comment: Can you share what code have you tried ? Are you using Eclipse ?

Comment: package AutomationSample;



import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;



public class HelloWorld {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\UsrName\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32");

 WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(); 


 driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");

}}

Comment: chromeDriver.exe is missing in setProperty

Comment: Now I have changed  that and executed it again
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Usrname\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

but getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the driver extension like below :

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\chromedriver_win32.exe");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();